# Meteor, cannot remove bootstrap 2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, dependencies

I'm trying to change my twitter bootstrap version from 2 to 3 but it turns out that I always have the bootstrap 2 added. I've made a grep `grep -Ri bootstrap *` on my project folder with no luck.
This is the list of packages I'm using `meteor list --using | sort`:

- accounts-base
- accounts-password
- accounts-twitter
- bootboxjs
- collection-api
- crypto-base
- crypto-md5
- email
- fancybox
- filepicker
- font-awesome
- fullcalendar
- holder
- http
- insecure
- iron-router
- iron-router-progress
- jquery-ui
- jquery-ui-bootstrap
- jquery-ui-sortable
- moment
- preserve-inputs
- standard-app-packages
- streams
- underscore
- underscore-string-latest

And this is the list of packages I get once the app is started
[image: screenshot of the paca]

So my question would be, **how do I get the rid of TB2** or **how can I check which is the package is adding it as a dependency**?

Comment: `bootboxjs` is probably the culprit. Have you checked?

Comment: Yep. I did. It seems it has no dependency declared. Nor in the smart.json neither in the lib folder

Comment: It uses bootstrap: https://github.com/TimHeckel/meteor-bootboxjs/blob/master/package.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Todolb and @Peppe L-G
It was **definitively** `bootboxjs`. It seems there's a pull request to update it to the latest version. I've forked the repo and fixed it.